# is string variable and string variable with string.empty same?

Tags: c#

I have many scenarios in my application where I am declaring strings as string.empty and later dynamically adding values to it. In C#, Is

```
string status
```

and

```
string status = String.Empty;
```

same?

Comment: No, string is reference type default is null.

Comment: String is a reference type.  It defaults to `null`.  You may or may not care.

Comment: String.Empty is the same as ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those lines of code are not equivalent.

- If you've declared `string status` outside of a method, it initializes to its default value of `null`.
- If you've declared `string status` *inside* a method, it isn't initialized, and you can't use it until you explicitly give it a value.

Whether or not you need `string status = String.Empty;` depends on your situation, but it seems like a decent way of avoiding a `NullReferenceException` if you find your code sometimes throws.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not the same. String datataype allows null. And remember that it is encouraged that you always initialize all your variables/attributes/properties.

```
string status = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the default value of *string* variable is *Null*

> string status;

- when inside a method:  it would stay uninitialized
- when outside a method:  it would create a string object with a *Null* value, because *string* is a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> string status = String.Empty;

will create a string object with a value of *the Empty constant* which is a string of zero length

Comment: *will create a string object with a Null value* wrong, that only happens on class-level variables, on a method it will not compile as it will be uninitialized.